# How to append new element in JSON file without get all data of this file in PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel

i need to append some elements to json file 
this is my code:
    **routes.php** (stage1)

```
$array = ['id' => '1', 'number' => '123123', 'name' => 'ahmed'];
$json_array = json_encode($array);
Storage::append('test.json', json_encode(['user_name' => 'ahmedsk']));
```

**test.json**

```
{"user_name":"ahmedsk"}
{"id":"1","number":"24142","username":"ahmedsk"}
```

but when i make print_r() for $result it's not feedback

**routes.php** (stage2)

```
$result = Storage::get('test.json');
print_r($result);
```

With knowing i don't need to use the method of get all data from JSON file and edited it and resave it in file.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't understand it at all. Try to describe your problem better. What for example "*`$result` is not feedback*" means? Maybe also add an output of `var_dump($result)` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is some how vague.
if you need to print the json file as an array this is what you need :

**routes.php** (stage2)

```
$result = Storage::get('test.json');
print_r(json_decode("[" . preg_replace("/\n+/",",",$result) . "]"));
```

test :
    https://eval.in/499591